# Undoing CSS specification

Tags: css

Can you, and if so how do you, undo a css specification? Suppose you wanted

```
textarea { width: 500px; }
```

and then you want a specific textarea with 70 columns:

```
<textarea class='email' cols=70></textarea>
```

Ideally, I would write a css rule

```
textarea.email { width: revert_to_default_unspecified_value; }
```

(but obviously that value doesn't exist.)

How do you do this? I'm interested in both this specific case, and also how to undo parent css specifications in children. This must have been talked about plenty, but it's hard to google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default value you're looking for is:

> *Initial:*    auto

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property

Notice that setting `auto` will revert to default for just some of the CSS properties. Other have different initial values.

The `background-color` property, for example, has a default value of `transparent`.

> *Initial:*    transparent

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background

Some of the properties, like `color`, can't be restored to a default because they don't have a known default.

> *Initial:*    depends on user agent

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#colors

---

#### About undoing inherited CSS in children.

Let's take the font-size property, a property that inherits.

```
level0
<div style="font-size:36px;">
    level1
    <div [style="font-size:medium;"]>
        level2
    </div>
</div>
```

By default the `level2` font size would be inherited from `level1`, but if we add the initial `medium` value we reset it to the size of the `level0` text. The only inconvenient is that we can't ignore just one level of inheritance, so if we would add a `level3`, we would still be resetting to `level0`, and not `level1`.

Answer (score 6):

```
textarea.email { width: auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that since if you do not specify a css `width` rule at all for this textarea, its default value would be `width: auto`. Thus I would try in the specific case setting it back to the default where the HTML attributes should take over as normal:

```
textarea.email { width: auto }
```

Answer (score 0):

To reset styles you can now use `unset` and `initial` special properties. The support for `unset` is currently low (56%) -http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS%20unset%20value but support for `initial` is quite high (80%) - http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS%20initial%20value.

Consider the example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMROye

```
<div class="outer">
  Foo
  <div class="middle">
    Bar
    <div class="inner">
      Baz
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.outer {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #f3f;
}

.middle {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #33f;
}

.inner {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #f33;
}

.inner {
  font-size: unset;
  color: unset;
}
```

The inner text will have font-size and color like its' parent.

If we change our last style to:

```
.inner {
  font-size: initial;
  color: initial;
}
```

The inner text will have standard color and standard font-size.

Now it is the best time to point out that these properties are a little trickier than they look, for example `unset` sometimes acts like `initial` and sometimes acts like `inherit`.

Links to docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value